# Including PHPMailer with Wordpress : Class 'PHPMailer' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I'm trying to include PHPMailer 6 in my functions.php file in Wordpress but have some issues.

I included the code in my functions.php file, then I call the new PHPMailer() in one of my custom class, but I have the "Class 'PHPMailer' not found" error.

```
<?php

include('src/tools/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');
include('src/tools/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
include('src/tools/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');

include('src/class/Email.php');
?>
```

When I try to call it with "new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();" I get a 500 internal server error.

```
<?php

class Email{

    private $_mail;

    public function __construct(){

        // Préparation des paramètres du mail
        $this->_mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        $this->_mail->isSMTP(); 
        ...
```

My tree view :

[image]

Anybody already had this issue ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the exact error message? (See [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) for more details.)

Comment: This is the exact message : PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /Applications/MAMP_2018-11-14_14-56-20/MAMP/cria/wp-content/themes/cria/src/class/Email.php on line 17. "Line 17" is my $this->_mail = new PHPMailer();"

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: In your error comment you say your code is `new PHPMailer`, but in the code you posted in the question it uses the FQCN of `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer` - which is it? If you have no `use` statements, the posted code is correct.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, when I use “new PHPMailer()” I have the “class PHPMailer not found” error. When I use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(), I have an 500 error

Comment: I use PHP7.3 version